# UITableViewCell imageView repeating

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, accessory

I am fairly new to iphone development, and I am trying to create my own "invite your friends" system using UITableViewCell. I Have checked other posts, but i do not know how to fix it. One problem i am having right now is, my UITableViewCell accessorys are repeating. for example. when I click this checkbox.

http://min.us/mCHcd3kwI
here is my project link if anyone decides to look at it

[image]

and if i scroll down, other checkboxs are also marked

[image]

I am wondering how can i fix this.

here is my code

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return 4;
        break;
    case 1:
        return [aArray count];
        break;
    case 2:
        return [bArray count];
        break;
    case 3:
        return [cArray count];
        break;
    case 4:
        return [dArray count];
        break;
    case 5:
        return [eArray count];
        break;
    case 6:
        return [fArray count];
        break;
    case 7:
        return [gArray count];
        break;
    case 8:
        return [hArray count];
        break;
    case 9:
        return [iArray count];
        break;
    case 10:
        return [jArray count];
        break;
    case 11:
        return [kArray count];
        break;
    case 12:
        return [lArray count];
        break;
    case 13:
        return [mArray count];
        break;
    case 14:
        return [nArray count];
        break;
    case 15:
        return [oArray count];
        break;
    case 16:
        return [pArray count];
        break;
    case 17:
        return [qArray count];
        break;
    case 18:
        return [rArray count];
        break;
    case 19:
        return [sArray count];
        break;
    case 20:
        return [tArray count];
        break;
    case 21:
        return [uArray count];
        break;
    case 22:
        return [vArray count];
        break;
    case 23:
        return [wArray count];
        break;
    case 24:
        return [xArray count];
        break;
    case 25:
        return [yArray count];
        break;
    case 26:
        return [zArray count];
        break;
}}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

if([tableView isEqual:self.myTableView]){
    static NSString *TableViewIdentifier = @"MyCells";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableViewIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *group;
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;


    if([selectedRowsArray containsObject:[content objectAtIndex:row]]){
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"];
    }else {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected@2x.png"];
    }
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleChecking:)];
     [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];


    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            group = [suggestedPeople objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 1:
            group = [aArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 2:
            group = [bArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 3:
            group = [cArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 4:
            group = [dArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 5:
            group = [eArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 6:
            group = [fArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 7:
            group = [gArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 8:
            group = [hArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 9:
            group = [iArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 10:
            group = [jArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 11:
            group = [kArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 12:
            group = [lArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 13:
            group = [mArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 14:
            group = [nArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 15:
            group = [oArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 16:
            group = [pArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 17:
            group = [qArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 18:
            group = [rArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 19:
            group = [sArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 20:
            group = [tArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 21:
            group = [uArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 22:
            group = [vArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 23:
            group = [wArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 24:
            group = [xArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 25:
            group = [yArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;

        case 26:
            group = [zArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
    }

}
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Apple does not recommend using the grouped table view style in combination with the index shown at the right side. IMO they're right, 'cause it looks ugly.

Comment: What does your array `content` represent, and how does it relate to the arrays `aArray`, `bArray`, `cArray`, etc?

Comment: "content" is an array full of first name/last name property of addressbook, the aArray, bArray, cArray, etc. Is list of last names that start with that alphabet

Comment: //if(cell == nil)     commend this line....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are only storing the `row` to determine whether a cell is checked or not. Since every section has a cell at index 0/1, this does not work as you want it to.

```
if([selectedRowsArray containsObject:[content objectAtIndex:row]]){
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"];
}else {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected@2x.png"];
}
```

Replace it with this: (assuming you you have an `NSMutableSet` as a property `self.selectedIndexPaths`)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    if ([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected@2x.png"];
    }
    ...
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me, do you know any examples/open source codes i can look into?

Comment: What exactly did not work? Can you maybe share your whole project. I can take a look at it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your code and what you are trying to achieve. Your app crashes when I try to run it. Also, only one section is populated with cells.

Comment: what do you mean one section is populated with cells?

Answer (score 0):

when you set up the cell each time you need to remove the subview/set it to nil. that is the checkmark from the  " earlier" cell since it is being reused by the table view.

Comment: He's explicitly setting the value of the cell's existing `imageView.image` property every time `cellForIndexPath:` is called.  If he were adding his own imageView I would agree the problem could be he needs to remove it when the cell is reused, but in this case I don't think that's the case.

Comment: ahh. i didn't actually read through all the switches and such. :p

Answer (score 0):

If your are using grouped style them make sure to handle the indexing properly because every section will have same type of indexing mean if u have 2 section with 3 rows then in these two sections the index.row will give 0,1,2 for every section

and also u have to handle the reuseable property of the cells i.e it creats only those cells which are currently visisble and then again reuse them when u scrll the table so when u sroll back to your previous cell which have u checked before will be shown you as unchecked though it is checked.

hope this will help you sorry for my bad english cause it is not my native language :)